# How to create a reusable widget which is wrapped by multiple Selectors in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Is it possible to build a widget which can be reused and also listens to only one specific `ChangeNotifier`? Let me explain with an example:

I have 3 ChangeNotifier: `NotifierA`, `NotifierB` and `NotifierC` and I have a widget named `MyLikeWidget` which shows like count and all three ChangeNotifier contain a variable representing that like count. If I want to reuse `MyLikeWidget` I can do this:

```
 class ReusableWidget extends StatelessWidget {
   const ReusableWidget({Key? key, required this.changeNotifierType}) : super(key: key);
   final int changeNotifierType;

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return changeNotifierType == 0 
        ? Selector<NotifierA, int>(
            selector: (c, notifierA) => notifierA.likeCount
            builder: (context, likeCount, child) => MyLikeWidget(likeCount: likeCount),
          )
        : changeNotifierType == 0
        ? Selector<NotifierB, int>(
            selector: (c, notifierB) => notifierB.likeCount
            builder: (context, likeCount, child) => MyLikeWidget(likeCount: likeCount),
          )
        : Selector<NotifierC, int>(
            selector: (c, notifierC) => notifierC.likeCount
            builder: (context, likeCount, child) => MyLikeWidget(likeCount: likeCount),
          );
   }
 }

class MyLikeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyLikeWidget({Key? key, required this.likeCount}) : super(key: key);
  final int likeCount;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ComplexWidget(
      ....
    );
  }
}
```

The above approach can work if we have only a few reusable widgets and few ChnageNotfiers, but for large complex apps this approach will result in a lot of boilerplate code, we can solve this by using Selctor3 but this approach will rebuild `MyLikeWidget` every time like count changes in any `ChangeNotifier` this approach can create problems for complex reusable widgets like a reusable video widget which will rebuild even it is playing a video if the value it is listening to changes in any `ChangeNotfier`.

Is there any other way we can approach this problem without writing a lot of boilerplate code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work - simply use the generics with your class:

```
class ReusableWidget<T extends ChangeNotifierProvider> extends StatelessWidget {
   const ReusableWidget<T>({super.key});
   

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Selector<T, int>(
            selector: (c, notifierA) => notifierA.likeCount
            builder: (context, likeCount, child) => MyLikeWidget(likeCount: likeCount),
          );
   }
 }
```

And use it like this:

```
return ReusableWidget<NotifierA>(
...
```